# jQuery disable multiple attributes at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner and I'm wondering if there is a way to remove multiple attributes once without coding for each one.

For an example, please look at my code sample below.

```
$(".select-us").attr("disabled",true);
$(".select-as").attr("disabled",true);
$(".select-eu").attr("disabled",true);
$(".select-oc").attr("disabled",true);
```

I just want to know if there is any simpler way to do this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".select-us, .select-as, .select-eu, .select-oc").attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please wrap your multiple form elements in fieldset and disable/ enable this only

```
<fieldset id='fset' disabled={true}>
...
```

can disable and enable with jquery like this

```
$("#fset").attr('disabled', true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a new class to every element like "select-all" and do:

```
       $(".select-all").attr("disabled",true);
```